# Consuming NetSuite service in WP7, CookieContainer not working

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, cookies, soap, netsuite

I'm using NetSuite webservice in my WP7 project.

This is the link that I use (the newer version):
https://webservices.na1.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2012_1_0/netsuite.wsdl

This worked perfectly in my C# console application, but not in WP7.

In WP7, it logs in successfully, but when adding anything (employee, customer, timebill, ...) I get the following error:

```
"Your connection has timed out.  Please log in again"
```

UPDATE:

this is my console code:

```
    NetSuiteService service = new NetSuiteService();

    service.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

    Passport passport = new Passport();
    passport.account = "TSTDRVxxxxxx";
    passport.email = "hamzeh.soboh@para-solutions.com";

    RecordRef role = new RecordRef();
    role.internalId = "3";
    passport.role = role;

    passport.password = "passxxxx";
    Status status = service.login(passport).status;
```

and the following is my WP7 code:

```
    NetSuitePortTypeClient service = new NetSuitePortTypeClient();

    // service.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

    Passport passport = new Passport();
    passport.account = "TSTDRVxxxxxx";
    passport.email = "hamzeh.soboh@para-solutions.com";

    RecordRef role = new RecordRef();
    role.internalId = "3";
    passport.role = role;

    passport.password = "passxxxx";
    service.loginAsync(passport);
```

uncommenting the second statement causes a runtime error.

Comment: The issue is probably due to the session not being maintained as the cookies probably aren't being (re)sent or (re)sent correctly. Can you show an example that does work (in the console app) and the WP7 code that doesn't? Have you tried profiling the network traffic (using Fiddler or similar) to see what's different?

Comment: You're right about the cookies. Please see my update. Thanks.

Comment: Have you solved this issue ? If yes, could you say how ? Thanks

Comment: @Rastko, actually, I stopped there assuming that Windows Phone is not supported. However, you can recheck.

Answer (score 0):

Try without cookies, something like this:

```
        // Instantiate the NetSuite web services
        netSuiteService = new DataCenterAwareNetSuiteService(*yourAccountNumber*);
        netSuiteService.Timeout = 1000 * 60 * 60;

        var appInfo = new ApplicationInfo();
        //App info from application netsuite
        appInfo.applicationId = *yourApplicationId*;

        // Prepare login credentials for request level login
        netSuiteService.passport = new Passport()
        {
            email = yourEmail*,
            password = *yourPassword*,
            account = *yourAccountNumber*
        };

        netSuiteService.applicationInfo = appInfo;

        Prefs = new Preferences();
        netSuiteService.preferences = Prefs;
        SearchPreferences = new SearchPreferences();
        netSuiteService.searchPreferences = SearchPreferences;
        Prefs.warningAsErrorSpecified = true;
        Prefs.warningAsError = false; 
        SearchPreferences.bodyFieldsOnly = false;
```